# ICE servers URL

Tags: url, webrtc

Why there is no `://` in the URL of the ICE servers?

```
stun:stun.example.com
turn:turn.example.com
```

Is the following valid too?

```
stun://stun.example.com
turn://turn.example.com
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definitions say these URLs are not valid with slashes:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7064

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7065

The "why" is hard to answer, you would have to crawl the IETF mailing list archives for that rationale.